# Преобразовать тип HSSFCell в String

Tags: apache, poi

Добрый день.
Есть метод.

```
private void readFile() {
     List<HSSFCell> lines = null;
     HSSFWorkbook myExcelBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
     HSSFSheet myExcelSheet = myExcelBook.getSheet("xxx"); //Получаем лист
     HSSFRow row = myExcelSheet.getRow(0); //Получаем строку
     lines.add(row.getCell(0));
```

}

У меня есть таблица эксель, я читаю ее с помощью метода выше. как мне преобразовать тип HSSFCell в String[]? Мне нужно чтобы при чтении файла у меня формировался список массивов строк.

Comment: `lines.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());` - это для получения текстового значения, а если значение другое (цифры), то будет ошибка. В коде указано получение у первого столбца первой ячейки, Вы так и хотите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getDateCellValue` - получить дату из ячейки
`.getErrorCellValue` - получить ошибку из ячейки
`.getNumericCellValue` - получить число из ячейки
`.getStringCellValue` - получить строку из ячейки

Получение определенных типов непредназначенным методом вернёт ошибку

Данный пример принимает массив `HSSFCell[]` и возвращает `String[]`

```
String[] cellsToString(HSSFCell[] cells){
    ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0, dataType = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
        try{
            switch(dataType){
                case 0:
                    buffer.add(cells[i].getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    buffer.add(String.valueOf(cells[i].getNumericCellValue()));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    buffer.add(String.valueOf(cells[i].getDateCellValue()));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    buffer.add(String.valueOf(cells[i].getErrorCellValue()));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if(dataType >= 4) e.printStackTrace();
            else{
                i--;
                dataType++;
            }
        }
    }

    String[] toReturn = {};
    return buffer.toArray(toReturn);
}
```